# Google Chrome, the best bet for online privacy?

Tags: web-application, privacy, web-browser, account-security, web

You may think I'm crazy, that's why I'm here to ask. [I read this page](https://digdeeper.neocities.org/ghost/browsers.html) which went over the privacy and security of many if not all browsers.

From his reporting, and my own logic, that the government likely has advanced enough tracking tech that no-browser on the market can escape the honeypot/tracking, I reason that using google chrome may be the safest avenue: Why? Because the larger the crowed, the less attention each user is given, and thus the greater privacy you get.

**Should I make the switch back to chrome from Brave?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments seems to be based on the assumption that the majority of tracking is done based on the browser type - which it is not. It is instead based on simple things like cookies, Etag etc but also on more complex things like Javascript based fingerprinting. Such fingerprints do not only depend on the type of browser used, but also on capabilities of the hardware and OS where the browser is running on. Thus the idea of being "part of a larger croud" using the same browser type does not really hold since there are enough ways to be more granular than just based on browser type. And how granular this can be actually depends on the browser, some (like Brave) explicitly try to limit the tracking.

> ... that the government likely has advanced enough tracking

The majority of tracking is not done by governments anyway. It is done by private companies trying to create user profiles and monetizing these with targeted ads. In countries where the government really wants to track individual users they can count on the cooperation of ISP in order to map individual IP addresses to specific house holds. And within a house hold there are only a few users and browser sessions which are much easier to distinguish from each other.

Comment: Ok, What is your final recommendation then? Stick with brave?

Comment: @NCT127: There are several browsers with more privacy focus than Chrome, like Brave but also Firefox. Chrome itself can also be augmented with extensions for blocking tracking and ads though. I'm not comfortable with making a clear recommendation of what is actually best. But with Google Chrome there is definitely an obvious conflict of interest since Google is a company which makes most of the money with tracking and profiling users and selling ads based on these profiles.